# While-Loop Syntax for C#, What have I done wrong?

Tags: c#, while-loop, syntax

Visual Studio is telling me that my bracket is incorrect and was instead expecting a bracket.

I've tried looking at the Unity manual, but I must be misunderstanding it because I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    while (Health > 3)
    {
        Health++;
        Debug.Log(Health);
    } // VS is telling me the issue is this bracket.


    else
    {
        GameOver();
    }

}
```

Im trying to make the code, in singular increments, to count to three. After the player collides with an object three times the GameOver method is called.

Comment: you can't have `else` block by itself, compiler is looking for `if`

Comment: This while loop keeps running until the `Health` integer overflows to -1, is that your intention?

Comment: Aside from the `else` issue, check the condition on which the `while` loop will exit. Since that condition is based on a particular value of the field/property `Health`, take a very close look at what you do with `Health`, and when thus the exit condition for the while loop will happen...

Comment: Omg you're right, I feel so silly.

Answer (score 1):

A `while` loop does not have an `else` part. The `while` block executes in a loop; as soon as the condition is `false`, the loop ends and execution continues with the statement *after* the loop, there is no reason/need to put `else` there.

But in your case, you probably do not want a loop at all. Your trigger gets triggered on every collision, I guess. So you really meant an `if` condition, where the `else` branch is completely fine.

Also, I guess you either wanted `Health--` to decrease health, *or* you wanted `Health < 3` for counting collisions (and probably rename the variable to `CollisionCount` or some such?).

So, your code should be

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (Health > 0)
    {
        Health--;
        Debug.Log(Health);
    }
    else
    {
        GameOver();
    }
}
```